# angular ui-grid - scrolling over absolute div scrolls grid content

Tags: css, angularjs, scroll, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to implement a custom ui-grid column filter with an autocomplete directive and I'm stuck with a scrolling behaviour over my autocomplete list. The list of filter options doesn't scroll when hovered. It scrolls a grid content first, and when scroll hits the bottom (or top) starts to scroll options list. I know, it's a general css problem.

here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lRnBQm1Dkemt4jsJfrhW?p=preview)

The list of option `filter-child` has `position:absolute` with `z-index`. Any ideas how to make scrolling behaviour correct - when hover on `filter-child` scrolls only list of options and not grid rows?

thanks !

Comment: Does anyone has any ideas what could be wrong? I'm really suck on this one. If my explanation of the problem isn't clear let me know, I will try to express myself better.